# Does fixed preprendet string in a MySql indexed table cause performance issues?

Tags: mysql, database, optimization, indexing, query-optimization

I got a MySql InnoDB Table containing a `source` field with about one Billion rows. All the source field values are urls, so they all start with `http://` (No https).

Does it increase the select performance on the `source` field if I remove all the `http://` start from the values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends.

I assume you have an index on your `source` field. Indexes on varchar fields in MySQL only work on prefixes, i.e. they can only be used when searching for either the whole value (`... where source = "some value"`) or a substring of the value starting at position 0 (`... WHERE source LIKE "some value%"`). If you query for arbitrary substrings (i.e. `... WHERE source LIKE "%some value%"`), MySQL cannot use the index.

When creating an index on a varchar or text column, you can optionally specify an index length (`KEY indexName (source(10))`). If you do, the index will only cover (in this example) the leftmost 10 characters of the URL. If you don't specify an index length, the whole field value is indexed - this makes the index larger, but more *selective* (index selectivity is the number of different values in your index divided by the total number of indexed values. The closer this ratio is to 1, the better). If you're using a TEXT or BLOB type, an index length is required. Now, if you have an index, have set an index length and query for a URL prefix as described above, then yes, removing "http://" from the URLs will make your index more selective and thus faster. How much faster depends on your data, the index length, and how much more selective your index becomes, so you should really measure it. I doubt, though, that it will ultimately make much difference, and if it does, you might gain much more by tinkering with the index.

If you don't query for URL prefixes or complete URLs, you might want to preprocess your URLs to be able to create an index that works with your query. If you don't have an index at all, then making an effective one should be your first optimization step.